# What happened when call std::map's operator[] or insert

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, constructor

I have following code:

```
#include <functional>   // std::less
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Key
{
public:
        Key() {cout << "Key Constructor" << endl;}
        ~Key() {cout << "Key Destructor" << endl;}
        Key(const Key& key) {cout << "Key Copy Constructor" << endl;}

        bool operator < (const Key& k1) {return true;}
};
int main()
{
        map<Key, int> mymap;
        Key k;

        cout << "operator[]"<<endl;
        mymap[k] = 1;

        map<Key, int> mymap2;
        cout << "insert"<<endl;
        mymap2.insert(std::make_pair(k, 1));
        cout << "=========" << endl;

}
```

And the output is:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -fpermissive
$ ./a.out
Key Constructor
operator[]
Key Copy Constructor
Key Copy Constructor
Key Destructor
insert
Key Copy Constructor
Key Copy Constructor
Key Copy Constructor
Key Copy Constructor
Key Destructor
Key Destructor
Key Destructor
=========
Key Destructor
Key Destructor
Key Destructor
```

Could anyone please explain why mymap[k] = 1; invoke 2 copy constructor and mymap2.insert(std::make_pair(k, 1)); invokes 4 copy constructor? and does that mean operator[] is much more efficient than insert?

Thanks.

**Summary:**

Thanks user 6502 and petersohn for your insight, I now guess the reason for the 2 extra copy constructor for insert is as below:

- [make_pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/?kw=make_pair) is a function, it make a copy inside function first, and then return the copy - that is one extra copy
- make_pair(k, 1) will create a `pair<Key, int>`, but the required [value_type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) is `pair<const& Key, int>`, the type conversion will cause another extra copy

So in case 2, if I use:

```
mymap2.insert(std::pair<const Key, int>(k, 1));
```

The number of copy constructors get called will be the same with operator[]

As 6502 noted, following [claim](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/) has been changed hence not true anymore:

> A call to this function(operator[]) is equivalent to:
>   (*((this->insert(make_pair(x,mapped_type()))).first)).second

operator[] is implemented different to avoid extra copy introduced by make_pair()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with insert is that `make_pair` will create a pair of the wrong type so the passed object will need a conversion to a proper pair type to be passed to `insert`.

Actually in a former version the C++ standard mandated `map::operator[]` to behave as `insert` (thus forcing an inefficient implementation). Later the text was relaxed allowing a better implementation.

Note anyway that for standard containers the elements are considered to be "values", i.e. the implementation is free to copy things around and you get no guarantees about how many copies will be made.

You can see the `make_pair` problem by changing the code to

```
    mymap2.insert(std::pair<const Key, int>(k, 1));
```

### Longer explanation

The problem is that `make_pair` will create an `std::pair<Key, int>` value but `insert`  signature wants instead a `const std::pair<const Key, int>&` (note that `std::map::value_type` is a pair with a `const` first element).

These two types are incompatible and unrelated so to be able to make the call another pair must be created copying both key and value and this is where an extra key duplication occurs.

Even if it could be apparently "logical" that a `pair<X, Y>` should be directly usable where `pair<const X, Y>` is expected this is not true in C++ and it's one of the logical problems of the const-correctness concept (it doesn't scale by composition).

Comment: Use const Key& is not fair as it hide the problem of the fact how Key is copied, actually, if I call mymap2.insert(std::make_pair<const Key&, int>(k, 1)); the number of constructor decreased to 2 as well.

Comment: I think there are 2 reasons for 2 extra constructor: one is what you mentioned as type conversion (but not caused by make_pair directly), just I use the wrong type, it should be: make_pair<const Key, int>; and the other reason is make_pair is a function, it will create a copy inside and then return a copy of it - one extra copy

Comment: _Actually in a former version the C++ standard mandated map::operator[] to behave as insert_ Doesn't it still?

Comment: @OpenLearner: No doesn't. Document N3242=11-0012 in 23.4.4.3 says that `T& operator[](const key_type& x)` is required to `"insert value_type(x, T())"` only if no key equivalent to `x` is present. The old description instead was requiring equivalence to an `insert` call in all cases (including a bad `make_pair` call).

Answer (score 2):

It's because of `make_pair`. You have to copy `k` into the pair, plus there is an extra function call. Possibly the number of copies can be reduced by enabling optimization (I didn't try). However, if you do this, then you'll have exactly the same number of copies than with operator[]:

```
mymap2.insert(std::pair<const Key&, int>(k, 1));
```

In C++11 though, things start to get better. If you compile your code with C++11, then you'll get two copies with insert. Even better, if `Key` has a move constructor, you'll get one copy and one move for insert (while two copies with operator[]). If you use my line above in C++11, you'll even spare the move and only get one copy.

Interestingly, with operator[], I always get two copies, for which I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "better". For sure they're not *simpler* so understanding what is going to happen will be harder.

Comment: It may be harder to understand, but it generally behaves better. As a rule of thumb, if you have a move constructor (and move assignment operator) that moves the contents of an object to another more efficiently than a copy, then in several cases you'll get a faster code than if you only had copy constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: interesting, seems operator[] and insert are implemented quite differently in stl

Comment: @lzprgmr: when I was reading the C++ standard I found the description of `operator[]` in terms of `insert` and found that (luckily) no implementation was following the standard on it (especially because the `insert` code was also creating a pair of the wrong type, like your example). I raised the issue and later the standard was changed to avoid providing an explicit (bad) implementation.

Comment: @6502 what do you mean insert will create a pair of the wrong type? I think I as a user pass in the wrong type which needs to be casted

Comment: @lzprgmr: in the old description the code for `operator[]` was calling `make_pair<K, V>`, thus creating `pair<K, V>` instead of `pair<const K, V>` that was needed by insert.Note that the whole idea of describing `operator[]` in terms of `insert` is broken (for example forces creating a default value even when it's not needed). Of course no standard library implementation was following this bad idea and in the end the standard was fixed (relaxed).