# std::map: why copy constructor is called two times?

Tags: c++, makefile, copy-constructor, stdmap, std-pair

Let's consider this simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class my_class {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    public:
    my_class():name(""), age(0) {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    my_class(std::string nm, int a) : name(nm), age(a) {
        std::cout << "Constructor with both parameters" << std::endl;
    }
    my_class(const my_class& obj) {
        std::cout << "copy_constructor " << std::endl;
        name = obj.name;
        age = obj.age;
    }
    void show() {
        std::cout << "name=: " << name << "age=: " << age <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, my_class> m;
    m[0];
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it via this gcc (version of my gcc: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609):

```
g++ -o main main.cpp
```

After run we see that copy constructor has been called two times:

```
Default constructor
copy_constructor 
copy_constructor
```

First call of copy constructor it is because of operator[]. A call to this function is equivalent to:

```
(*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second
```

So we see that `make_pair` calls copy constructor of `my_class`.
But the reason of the second call of copy constructor is not clear for me. I'm only supposing that it creates a temporary object into make_pair implementation. Am I correct ?

Comment: Very weird. I [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3277f7db0c201af8), with clang and gcc. What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Try running in the debugger, setting a breakpoint in the copy constructor, and then check the call stack to see where it's being called.

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: It goes to read_black tree node creation constructor but the further debugging is pretty difficult

Comment: Rakete1111 - it's because you are using -std=c++14 flag. Compile it without this flag.

Comment: Are you building with optimization enabled?

Comment: No optimization flag has been used. To compile the code this command has been used: g++ -o main main.cpp

Comment: I think you can find answer to this question here:
[What happens when called std::map's operator[] or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247998/what-happened-when-call-stdmaps-operator-or-insert)